# FtpWebRequest UploadFile From String Data (not a file)

Tags: c#, streamreader, ftpwebrequest

There are many samples of c# code showing how to upload a file when a stream is being read from file on disk.

So I think I need to do a new `Stream`, but I do not understand what this means:

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(Stream stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was simple!

The StreamReader is to read a file into a stream. I did not need to worry about that.

I just needed to do the following:

byte[] stringContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My string data");